# Animation gets executed but then immediately returns to initial state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, animation

Here is my code, I'm calling in on a state change. It gets executed but then immediately returns to its initial state. I would like to make it hold its position until I tell it otherwise.

```
  const spinValue = new Animated.Value(0)
  const widthValueX = new Animated.Value(0)

  const open = () => {
    Animated.spring(widthValueX, {toValue: 2, useNativeDriver: true}).start()
    Animated.spring(spinValue, {toValue: 2, useNativeDriver: true}).start()
  }

  const growX = widthValueX.interpolate({
    inputRange: [0, 1, 2],
    outputRange: [1, 1.5, 1]
  })

  const spinX = spinValue.interpolate({
    inputRange: [0, 1, 2],
    outputRange: ['0deg', '45deg', '90deg']
  })
```

Comment: where is your state change function . can you share it ?

Comment: @MohammadFaisal I'm just calling the animation with open() that's it